# Cannot install office plugin

Tags: .net-4.0, ms-word, .net-4.5

I''m trying to install a word ribbon, that I created in vs2010 using .net framework 4. I tried installing it on my deployment pc but got an error : 
[image]

I tried installing the .net framework 4.0 and I get a message saying that I have the framework or a newer version of it. I went to add remove and I saw I have .net 4.5. How do I get around this? Is .net 4.5 compatible with 4.0 applications ? I would assume some sort of backward compatibility.

I don't want to uninstall the 4.5 framework. I need this plugin to work on word 2007,2010 and 2013

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I right clicked on the ribbon properties->publish

clicked on prerequisites and added this [image]

Comment: You may need to check the "Microsoft Office 20xx Primary Interop Assemblies" entries as well? Is there any other entry beside that for Office 2007? Which Office version has the target machine installed?

Comment: @DanielLemke those are the only 2 entries I have do I need more for 2013 or 2007?

Comment: Which Office version has the target machine installed?

Comment: @DanielLemke I am targeting windows 7 and 8. office 2010 and 2013. Please look ant this question I think you may be able to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601342/windows-8-word-ribbon-cant-access-com-class

Answer (score 0):

.NET 4.5 is a replacement for 4.0 so you cannot have both installed. From a .NET 4.0 applications view it shouldn't make a difference if there is .NET 4 or 4.5 installed.

But I guess the .NET version isn't the problem here. Did you actually followed the link provided in the dialog? It will point you to certain HowTo articles which describe the prerequisites for Microsoft Office Add-ins. Maybe you've just missed to include the "Microsoft Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies" in your setup.